# Golang CGO Exception 0x40010006

Tags: c++, go, cgo, seh

Im trying to run a function from a dll using cgo. The library is in c++ so I created a C header here are the functions defined and a `.cpp` file where is the implementation.

lib.h:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void* LoadEngine(char*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

lib.cpp:

```cpp
#include <Engine.h> //the library

void* LoadEngine(char *sn) {
  Engine *e;
  GetEngineObject(sn, &e); //function from the dll, here it fails
  return (void*) e;
}
```

then calling it with:

```golang
package main

/*
#include "lib.h"
*/
import "C"

func main() {
  e := C.LoadEngine(C.CString("foobar")
  ...
}
```

I have `go1.12 windows/amd64`
and `mingw-w64-posix-seh`

tried also `mingw-w64-posix-sjlj`, `mingw-w64-win32-seh`, `mingw-w64-win32-sjlj`, but the result is the same, or it doesn't compile at all

compiling it just with `go build` and:

```
#cgo windows CFLAGS: -IC:/Engine/Inc
#cgo windows CPPFLAGS: -IC:/Engine/Inc
#cgo windows LDFLAGS: -LC:/Engine/Bin64 -lEngine -lEngineObj -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid
```

On win8 it runs ok, but on win10+ it doesn't work, if the function gets to calling the `GetEngineObject` which is from the dll, it fails with:

```
Exception 0x40010006 0x1 0x8deb90 0x7ffbc9ada388
PC=0x7ffbc9ada388

runtime: unknown pc 0x7ffbc9ada388
stack: frame={sp:0x8dea80, fp:0x0} stack=[0x0,0x8dfdf0)
00000000008de980:  0000000002000002  000000002a080321
00000000008de990:  0000000090000191  0000000000000321
00000000008de9a0:  0000000500000008  0000000500000000
00000000008de9b0:  feeefeeefeeefeee  00000000024c0150
00000000008de9c0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
00000000008de9d0:  00000000024c0000  00007ffbccb730ac
00000000008de9e0:  0000000002680000  00000000024c1e30
00000000008de9f0:  00000000026a2d90  00000000026ad480
00000000008dea00:  0000000000000df1  0000000000000000
00000000008dea10:  0000000000000df1  0000000000000df1
00000000008dea20:  0000000000001bf8  0000000000000000
00000000008dea30:  0000000090000191  0000000000000003
00000000008dea40:  0000bcc3daf1f4cb  00000000026a2d00
00000000008dea50:  0000000000000000  000002fffb442d78
00000000008dea60:  0000000000000000  00000000008dfb00
00000000008dea70:  0000000000000020  00007ffbc9ada388
00000000008dea80: <00000000024c0000  000000002fbe1490
00000000008dea90:  00000000008df970  00000000ffffffff
00000000008deaa0:  0000000040010006  0000000000000000
00000000008deab0:  00007ffbc9ada388  0000000000000002
00000000008deac0:  0000000000000001  00000000008deb90
00000000008dead0:  00000000001b0150  0000000000800000
00000000008deae0:  00000000026ad480  0000000000000000
00000000008deaf0:  00000000001b10b0  0000000000690000
00000000008deb00:  00000000024c0000  00007ffbccbbcafa
00000000008deb10:  00000000024c0000  00007ffbccb76ff8
00000000008deb20:  00000000026a2d90  00000000026a9c30
00000000008deb30:  0000000000000000  0000000000000001
00000000008deb40:  00002c98037a65f6  000000000000001f
00000000008deb50:  00000000026a9430  000000002fd8a367
00000000008deb60:  0000000000006000  00000000024c0000
00000000008deb70:  0000000000000df1  0000000000000000
runtime: unknown pc 0x7ffbc9ada388
stack: frame={sp:0x8dea80, fp:0x0} stack=[0x0,0x8dfdf0)
00000000008de980:  0000000002000002  000000002a080321
00000000008de990:  0000000090000191  0000000000000321
00000000008de9a0:  0000000500000008  0000000500000000
00000000008de9b0:  feeefeeefeeefeee  00000000024c0150
00000000008de9c0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
00000000008de9d0:  00000000024c0000  00007ffbccb730ac
00000000008de9e0:  0000000002680000  00000000024c1e30
00000000008de9f0:  00000000026a2d90  00000000026ad480
00000000008dea00:  0000000000000df1  0000000000000000
00000000008dea10:  0000000000000df1  0000000000000df1
00000000008dea20:  0000000000001bf8  0000000000000000
00000000008dea30:  0000000090000191  0000000000000003
00000000008dea40:  0000bcc3daf1f4cb  00000000026a2d00
00000000008dea50:  0000000000000000  000002fffb442d78
00000000008dea60:  0000000000000000  00000000008dfb00
00000000008dea70:  0000000000000020  00007ffbc9ada388
00000000008dea80: <00000000024c0000  000000002fbe1490
00000000008dea90:  00000000008df970  00000000ffffffff
00000000008deaa0:  0000000040010006  0000000000000000
00000000008deab0:  00007ffbc9ada388  0000000000000002
00000000008deac0:  0000000000000001  00000000008deb90
00000000008dead0:  00000000001b0150  0000000000800000
00000000008deae0:  00000000026ad480  0000000000000000
00000000008deaf0:  00000000001b10b0  0000000000690000
00000000008deb00:  00000000024c0000  00007ffbccbbcafa
00000000008deb10:  00000000024c0000  00007ffbccb76ff8
00000000008deb20:  00000000026a2d90  00000000026a9c30
00000000008deb30:  0000000000000000  0000000000000001
00000000008deb40:  00002c98037a65f6  000000000000001f
00000000008deb50:  00000000026a9430  000000002fd8a367
00000000008deb60:  0000000000006000  00000000024c0000
00000000008deb70:  0000000000000df1  0000000000000000

goroutine 1 [syscall]:
path/to/package._Cfunc_LoadEngine(0x23a2c20, 0x0)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:518 +0x51
path/to/package.Load(0x4d05ad, 0x1d, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/microo8/Documents/workspace/src/path/to/package/fre.go:55 +0x89
main.main()
        W:/Workspace/src/path/to/package/test/test.go:12 +0x41
rax     0x3e00003e
rbx     0x2fbe1490
rcx     0xfffffffffffffffe
rdi     0xffffffff
rsi     0x8df970
rbp     0x20
rsp     0x8dea80
r8      0x2fca2793
r9      0x3a0f4c0
r10     0x2fca2701
r11     0x26aadb0
r12     0x8dfb00
r13     0x0
r14     0x2fffb442d78
r15     0x0
rip     0x7ffbc9ada388
rflags  0x202
cs      0x33
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b
```

I've also tried to catch the exception with mingw's `__try1` and `__except1` but it fails anyways. Tried different mingw versions, using `-ldflags="-linkmode internal"` but this doesn't compile and `-ldflags="-linkmode external"` makes also this exception.

*EDIT:* also tried to call the `LoadEngine` function (from `lib.h`) from a C program and it works fine. Compiled the `lib.cpp` with `g++` to `lib.o`. And linked it to `test.c` where I just called the `LoadEngine` just from `main` function. So maybe there is something wrong how go links the library to cgo?

Comment: If you have a simple C++ program that calls `GetEngineObject`, does it work, or does it crash as well? Where does this `GetEngineObject` function come from? What does it do? Can you debug and possibly fix problems in it?

Comment: I haven't run it just from C++, but I can try it. It is a proprietary library, I just have the header and dll. It does all sorts of things, not just loading the "engine", but also checks the licence key (the `sn` param) with a licence server, initializes the engine (loads some data from the disk), and maybe other things too.  How can I debug it? Can I use Visual Studio, or somehow the mingw's gdb?

Comment: Then if the crash is inside `GetEngineObject` you can't really debug it. You have to make sure that you're calling it correctly with valid arguments, and then create a [mcve] that you can send with a bug-report to the makers of the DLL.

Comment: I can try, but it is strange, that on win8 it works, and on win10 and win2016 it makes the  same `Exception 0x40010006` (`DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C`).

Comment: I've tried to run the function from C. Compiled the `lib.cpp` to lib.o with `g++` and have written a `test.c` where I just call the `LoadEngine` function from `lib.h` and it works. Maybe there is something about how go links the library?

Comment: Then start by making sure that the string argument is passed correctly. If it is then look closer how you build your Go application and how you link with the C++ code. Beyond that I can't help you more myself.

Comment: You may also want to edit your question to say that calling `GetEngineObject` from a C or C++ program works as expected. And remember that editing pushes your question back onto the front-page, so careful and gradual improvement of the question over a day or two should give it more exposure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason on win10+ it would raise the `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C`. Which is caused by the `OutputDebugStringW` and no debugger is listening.

I think normally it would be done with microsoft's [__try and __except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement?view=vs-2017), but in MinGW is just __try1 and __except1, which I think only works on 32bit systems (very little documentation is to that)

But I found, that you can add a [Exception Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/windows/desktop/Debug/vectored-exception-handling)

so now lib.cpp:

```cpp
#include <Engine.h> //the library
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>

LONG WINAPI VectoredHandler(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo) {
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ExceptionInfo);  
   return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;  //just continue
}
#endif


void* LoadEngine(char *sn) {
#ifdef _WIN32
  PVOID handler = AddVectoredContinueHandler(1, VectoredHandler);
#endif
  Engine *e;
  GetEngineObject(sn, &e);
#ifdef _WIN32
  RemoveVectoredContinueHandler(handler); 
#endif
  return (void*) e;
}
```

Because using the library starts with loading the engine and ends with unloading it, and the engine is a singleton, I've just made the `PVOID handler` also a global singleton and the `AddVectoredContinueHandler` is in `LoadEngine` and `RemoveVectoredContinueHandler` is in `UnloadEngine`.